# Meta analysis Model

Tags: meta-analysis, network-meta-analysis

I'm working on meta-analysis in the agricultural sciences.
I am looking for feedback on the rma.mv structure below for a multi-level model in metafor.
The data are structured such that: each group (4 groups) represents a specific treatment. each is nested by the crop that is nested by the study, which is nested by paper.
One paper can have multiple studies and within each study different Crops.
Not all groups are reported in all studies, and not all crops are reported in all studies
Paper>Study>Crop>Group

I am interested in comparing between the four groups for each crop x study within paper
Consistent with metafor (rma.mv), I've specified the random effects as study, paper, and Crop, coding the model to include the group as the inner variable.
Following a previous post, I got this model:

data$study.in.paper <- paste0(data$Paper, ".", data$Study)
fit <- rma.mv (yi, vi, mods = ~ group - 1,
random = list (~ group | study.in.paper, ~ group | paper),
data = data,
struct = "HCS")

I would like to know why this part (~ group | paper) was included, please

If I want to compare the groups for each study with the publication:

For random: random = list (~ group | study.in.paper) is not enough.

And if I want to include the crop in the model
Could be something like that

data$study.in.paper <- paste0(data$Paper, ".", data$Study)

fit <- rma.mv(yi, vi, mods = ~ group - 1,
random = list(~group | study.in.paper, ~ group | Crop),
data = wt2,
struct = "HCS")
or

I can add this line: data$crop.in.study.in.paper <- paste0(data$study.in.paper, ".", data$Crop)
and then will be something like that

fit <- rma.mv(yi, vi, mods = ~ group - 1,
random = list(~ group | crop.in.study.in.paper),
data = data,
struct = "HCS")

which code is accurate based on the described structure?

Sorry for the long question
I hope everything is clear

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is treatment really nested within crop? So crop 1 had treatment a, b, c, d and crop 2 had treatment e, f, g, h, and so so?

Comment: @mdewey sorry if this was not clear, but for example, I have treatment a, b, c for crop 1 and a, b only for crop 2

Comment: @mdewey Thank you for your question, I understand what you mean. this model is accurate   fit <- rma.mv(yi, vi, mods = ~ group - 1,
              random = list(~ group | study.in.paper),
              data = data,
              struct = "HCS")
  or I should include also (~ group | paper) ?

Comment: Treatment is crossed with crop then not nested.